# How to use google apis in Windows phone 8 application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, google-api

I am developing a windows phone application, which is a version of 8.0. I have uploaded an excel document on Google drive. How do I extract data from the document that I have uploaded on Google drive using Google APIs?

Comment: Please remove the WPF tag as Windows Phone does not use WPF. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [PedroLamas/GDrive](https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive) where you could try out these functions:

- Multiple accounts support
- OAuth 2 account login
- List files and folders with their metadata
- Navigate the folder tree
- Create new folders
- Upload files (just pictures, that's what Windows Phone SDK    allows
  us to do!)
- Star/Unstar files
- Rename files
- Trash files

Or else another option could be the, [Drive API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v2).